# Absolute and relative paths in an Asp.NET project

Tags: html, asp.net

When using `a` like so:

```
<a href="../One/Two/Three/Four.aspx">Search</a>
```

Does the `..` go back one directory from where it is clicked, or does it go to the root of the project structure?

**edit:** A better way to ask: I am referencing a .js file from my Master page, how do I keep the reference relative if I don't know the depth of child pages that will use the Master page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `..` folder means one level down from the current folder.

The browser can't go from the project root folder, because it doesn't know where that root folder is, or what the project is for that matter. You can use `/` at the beginning of an URL to go to the site root, but that may be different from the project root.

Answer (score 1):

It goes back one directory.

`/one/two/three/etc` Assumes that `/one` is in the root directory. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

`../One/Two/Three/Four.aspx` goes back one directory

`/One/Two/Three/Four.aspx` starts from the root

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which explains everything including the use of tilde (`~`)